# Moving Devise edit_user view to a Modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, twitter-bootstrap

How would I move the built in Devise edit_user_registration view to a modal so as when a use clicks on the settings link on a page a modal is shown instead of Rails routing to the view. I'm using bootstrap and wishing to use their code, but I'm unsure as to where one actually places the contents of your modal view in rails?

Will I have to override the devise path or even the controller?

Calling a modal is done via in any layout right... so

```
<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" >Launch Modal</a>
```

My initial thought was wrap my ..devise/registration/edit.html.erb with the appropriate Modal elements and id but I'm not sure if putting href= "#myModal" must be the same as the id of the modal or can i use the default devise edit route...

Im if i didn't use devise I wouldn't have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap performs some JS magic so that the href in your anchor tag href="#myModal" picks up a div with the same id and uses it to display as the contents as the modal.

What you want to do is this

```
<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" >Launch Modal</a>
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
   <%= render :template => "devise/registrations/edit" %>
</div>
```

This will render the devise view in your current view but it will be hidden thanks to bootstrap.  Then thanks to bootstrap when someone clicks the Launch Modal button it will show the hidden contents: your user edit form.

Comment: I'm using simple_form with my bootstrap and i'm getting undefined resource_name in my actions controller now but its progress, thanks

Comment: Now that you mention it I had this exact problem as well! I added these to application_helper.rb:  

    def resource_name
        :user
    end

    def resource
        \@resource ||= User.new
    end

    def devise_mapping
        @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
    end
  
    def resource_class
        User
    end